ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error. Flutter WEB
I get this error in my app.
and once i get this error, even though im catching it. it stops all my api requests to my back end django server from working
steps to reproduce:

i call an api to my django rest framework back end. works fine.

i shut off my back end server ( to simulate an outage)

api call from my flutter web app is then again made to a server that is not online

a ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error. is thrown. which is caught.

i turn my server back on. and then no further api calls are made to the  back end.


Is there any way around this in flutter web? (without disabling web security)
